# Using Room persistence library alongside with sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a project which use SqLite to store data. Now I want to create some tables and want to create those tables using Room persistence library.
Can I access same database using room and Sqlite Api?

This is my sqlite code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Table names
static final String TABLE_FOOD = "_food_table";
static final String TABLE_CUISINE = "_cuisine_table";
static final String TABLE_UNITS = "_units_table";
static final String TABLE_INGREDIENTS = "_ingredients_table";
static final String TABLE_CART = "_cart_table";
public static final String CLIENT_TABLE_CART = "_client_cart_table";
static final String TABLE_SUPPLIER = "_supplier_table";

private static final String DB_NAME = "duplate.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;
```

This is my Room database creation code

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(IngredientType::class), version = 3)
    abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

       abstract fun ingredientTypeDao(): IngredientTypeDao

       companion object {
           private val DB_NAME = "duplate.db"
          @Volatile
          private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = create(context)
            }
           return instance
        }

        private fun create(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    DB_NAME).build()
        }
    }}
```

I know I need to use migration. If migration is the handy to use this both api together. Need suggestion.
Now I want to access same database using sqlite or room. Will there be any problem? Any suggestion would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: Just use same DB name and everything will be fine, except this in log: SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE] database is locked

Answer (score 1):

> Can I access same database using room and Sqlite Api?

No you can't. `RoomDatabase` would be a totally separate database and you would have to slowly move your tables to the new database. That's the only way to use Room API.

If the tables you listed are the only tables in your project, it looks doable in a fairly short amount of time. I'd recommend that you create the new database entirely from scratch with `Entities` and `Daos`. Your biggest challenge will be to convert all your SQLite Queries into `Daos` and it may take the most amount of time, but it will be worth it in the end.

> I know I need to use migration. If migration is the handy to use this both api together.

Migration is only to handle database upgrades within `Room` database. This is the same as calling `onUpgrade` in SQLite.

Follow this guide to incrementally move to `Room`:
https://medium.com/google-developers/incrementally-migrate-from-sqlite-to-room-66c2f655b377